# Use globbed string in YAML

Tags: yaml, filebeat

I am looking for a way to dynamically set the key using the path of the file below.

For example if I have this YAML:

```
prospectors.config:
  - fields: 
    queue_name: <somehow get the globbed string below in here>
  paths: 
    - /var/log/casino/*.log
  type: log
output.redis: 
  hosts: 
    - "producer:6379"
  key: "%{[fields.queue_name]}"
```

And then I had a file called /var/log/casino/test.log, then key would become `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that what you want is possible.

You could use the [`source` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-log.html#_literal_source_literal) and configure your Redis output using that as the key:

```
output.redis: 
  hosts: 
    - "producer:6379"
  key: "%{source}"
```

This would have the disadvantage of being the absolute path of the source file, not the basename as your question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small number of possible basename patterns, and want a queue for each. For example, you have files:

```
/common/path/test-1.log
/common/path/foo-0.log
/common/path/01-bar.log
/common/path/test-3.log
...
```

and wanted to have three queues in redis `test`, `foo` and `bar` you could use the [`source` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-log.html#_literal_source_literal) and the conditionals available in the [`keys` configuration of redis output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/redis-output.html#_literal_keys_literal) something like this

```
output.redis: 
  hosts: 
    - "producer:6379"
  key: "default_key"
  keys:
    - key: "test_key"
      when.contains:
        source: "test"
    - key: "foo_key"
      when.contains:
        source: "foo"
    - key: "bar_key"
      when.contains:
        source: "bar"
```